# Kernel crashes when I add non-inline function

Tags: assembly, x86, g++, bootloader, osdev

I have written simple bootloader and kernel in *C* (compiling with g++ compiler).
When I try to create non-inline functions, the kernel crash refers to 0xefffff54.
Registers SS, DS and others are zero, but had been previously selector 0x10 in protected mode. Here is bootloader, loader, and kernel and how I link it:

**boot.asm**

```
use16
[org 0x7c00]
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

section .text

mov bp, 0x9990
mov sp, bp

call loadKernel

cli
lgdt [gdt_desc]

in al, 0x92
or al, 2
out 0x92, al

mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax

jmp 0x8:init_pm

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

use32
init_pm:
mov ax, 0x10
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax

mov esp, 0x9990

push ecx
push 1500
call clearConsole
add esp, 4
pop ecx

push eax
push edx

push 0x1B
push hello_world
push 0
call printStr
add esp, 12

pop edx
pop eax
jmp 0x1000
jmp $

;void loadKernel()
loadKernel:
use16
    mov bx, 0x1000
    mov ah, 0x2
    mov dl, 0x80
    mov al, 0x1
    mov ch, 0x0
    mov cl, 0x2
    mov dh, 0x0
    int 0x13
    ret

;void clearConsole(int value)
use32
clearConsole:
    mov ecx, 0
    loop_2:
    cmp ecx, [esp+4]
    jz exit_2
    mov al, 0
    mov ah, 0
    push ecx
    call printChar
    pop ecx
    add ecx, 2
    jmp loop_2
    exit_2:
    ret

;void printStr(byte num, char* str, byte color)
printStr:
    mov ecx, [esp+8]
loop_1:
    mov al, [ecx]
    inc ecx
    test al, al
    jz exit_1
    mov ah, [esp+12]
    push dword [esp+4]
    call printChar
    add esp, 4
    inc dword [esp+4]
    inc dword [esp+4]
    jmp loop_1
exit_1:
    ret

;void printChar(byte num, unsigned char c, byte color)
printChar:
    mov edx, 0xB8000
    add edx, [esp+4]
    mov [edx], al
    mov [edx+1], ah
    ret



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

hello_world:
db "Loading kernel...", 0

GDT:
;null
dd 0
dd 0

code:
dw 0xffff ; limit
dw 0    ; base
db 0    ; base
db 0x9a ; access rights
db 11001111b ; 4 left - flags, 4 right = limit
db 0        ; base

data:
dw 0xffff
dw 0
db 0
db 0x92
db 11001111b
db 0

gdt_desc:
dw $ - GDT -1
dd GDT

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

**loader.asm**

```
use32

section .bss
align 16
stack_bottom:
resb 16384
stack_top:

section .text
extern kernel_main
global _start

_start:
    mov esp, stack_top
    call kernel_main
    jmp $
```

**kernel_main.c**

```
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

uint16_t* g_pTerminalBuffer;

#define MAX_HEIGHT  25
#define MAX_WIDTH   80

#define true 1
#define false 0

uint8_t g_iTerminalRow;
uint8_t g_iTerminalColumn;

inline uint8_t encodeColor(uint8_t foreground, uint8_t background)
{
    return foreground | background << 4;
}

inline uint16_t encodeChar(uint8_t c, uint8_t color)
{
    return (uint16_t)color << 8 | (uint16_t)c;
}

void initializeTerminal() // fails when i add this function
{
    g_iTerminalRow = 0;
    g_iTerminalColumn = 0;
}

extern "C" void kernel_main()
{
    g_pTerminalBuffer = (uint16_t*)0xB8000;
    g_pTerminalBuffer[2] = encodeChar('T', encodeColor(15, 0));
    while(true){}
}
```

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
nasm -f elf32 loader.asm -o loader.o
~/cross/bin/i386-elf-c++ -ffreestanding -c /home/name/os/kernel_main.c -o /home/name/os/kernel_main.o

ld -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0x1000 -o kernel_main.elf kernel_main.o loader.o
objcopy -R .note -R .comment -S -O binary kernel_main.elf kernel_main.bin

dd if=/dev/zero of=image.bin bs=512 count=2880
dd if=boot.bin of=image.bin conv=notrunc
dd if=kernel_main.bin of=image.bin conv=notrunc bs=512 seek=1

rm ./boot.bin ./kernel_main.bin ./kernel_main.o ./loader.o ./kernel_main.elf
qemu-system-i386 -d guest_errors image.bin
```

Comment: Is the code posted here a version that fails? What do you mean by non-inline functions (I'm uncertain what is meant)? You read one sector of the kernel from your bootloader. Is your kernel image bigger than one sector(512 bytes)?Failure to load the entire kernel will result in problems.

Comment: In your loadKernel function you should be setting ES to 0. Your environment likely alread had ES set to 0 but it isn't guaranteed. As well you should consider not hard coding drive 0x80. When the BIOS passes control to your bootloader _DL_ already has the boot drive that was loaded from. You can use that for disk reads.

Comment: when i set ES to 0, bios cannot detect bootloader. Says Boot failed: not a bootable disk(size is < 512 bytes)

Comment: i build from the same directory where the files are located

Comment: try to run when the function initializeTerminal is not commented, it will crash i guess(qemu-system-i386)

Comment: So the code you posted is not a version that fails, but one that works. You should amend the question so you show us the version that fails and then explain what you wish to comment out to make it work.

Comment: sorry for that, i'm just newbie. It's edited(function is now uncommented)

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Your `loader.asm` is actually the entry point, not kernel_main. So try placing `loader.o` before `kernel_main.o` in your link step.

Comment: thank you very much, problem were solved by creating linking script and placing .bootloader(section .text renamed to .bootloader in loader.asm) at the 0x1000!

Comment: i have written linker script, now it works, thank you

Comment: In order to mark this question as closed, and my answer mentions usage of a linker script (at the bottom as an alternative) you may wish to consider marking the answer accepted (which is different from upvoting).More on how and why of dong this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/271768

Answer (score 1):

Without a linker script, the default ELF one will place `.text` (and `.text.startup`) sections followed by `.rodata*`, `.data`, and `.bss`. Functions in the `.text` section will be output to the executable in the order they are encountered. The linker *LD* will process objects in the order they are encountered on the command line. You do:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0x1000 -o kernel_main.elf kernel_main.o loader.o
```

*kernel_main.o* is first, so the functions in *kernel_main.o* will be processed **first**. When you defined `initializeTerminal` it is possible (and likely the case here) that it will appear before `kernel_main`. If `initializeTerminal` is the first function and you try to start executing there from the bootloader(at address 0x1000) you are going to get in an undefined state and it will likely cause a triple fault. The triple fault would put you back in real mode which is why your segments in a dump may have appeared to be reset to 0x0000.

If you remove `initializeTerminal` the first function encountered will be `kernel_main`. An astute observer might point out that you really didn't want `kernel_main` executed directly either! You want `_start` to be executed first! You were just lucky that `kernel_main` could be executed without error as is. You really want `_start` to appear before other functions.

The quick fix should be to move `loader.o` so that it is the first object in the linker command line:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -Ttext 0x1000 -o kernel_main.elf loader.o kernel_main.o
```

Now the`.text` section with `_start` will be processed and output to the final executable first. This should resolve your problem.

Alternatively I prefer creating a linker script that places the `.text` section in `loader.o` first in the executable. A proper linker script can avoid the hassle of worrying about the order that object files are specified on the command line.

---

Below I'm providing a version of the files that:

- Includes a linker script to place the .text` section of loader.o first folled by the rest.
- Linker script defines an origin point  (VMA) for the kernel of 0x1000.
- The linker script defines start and end symbols for the BSS section
- `loader.asm` initializes the BSS section to zero before calling the *C++* entry point.
- It is a good idea to put inline functions in header files. I split the video routines from kernel_main and placed the global video variables in *video.c* . The inline functions are in *video.h*.
- Use the value of *DL* passed by the BIOS to the bootloader containing the boot drive number.
- CHS disk reads (Int 13h/AH=02h) require the destination to be specified in ES:BX. Since we want the kernel loaded at 0x0000:0x1000 explicitly set ES to 0. It isn't guaranteed to be zero when your bootloader starts running.
- I build with optimizations on
- I build with debug information on. This can be useful when running the code in QEMU with a remote GDB debugger.

The files are:

**link.ld**:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386");
/* We define an entry point to keep the linker quiet. This entry point */
ENTRY(_start);

KERNEL_BASE = 0x1000;

SECTIONS
{
    . = KERNEL_BASE;

    .kernel : SUBALIGN(4) {
        /* Ensure .text section of loader.o is first */
        loader.o(.text*);
        *(.text*);
        *(.rodata*);
        *(.data*);
    }

    /* Place the unitialized data in the area after our kernel */
    .bss : SUBALIGN(4) {
        __bss_start = .;
        *(COMMON);
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __bss_end = .;
    }
    __bss_sizeb = SIZEOF(.bss);
    __bss_sizel = __bss_sizeb / 4;

    /* Remove sections that won't be relevant to us */
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame);
        *(.comment);
    }
}
```

**boot.asm**:

```
[ORG 0x7c00]
use16
section .text

mov bp, 0x9990
mov sp, bp

call loadKernel

cli
lgdt [gdt_desc]

in al, 0x92
or al, 2
out 0x92, al

mov eax, cr0
or eax, 1
mov cr0, eax

jmp 0x8:init_pm

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

use32
init_pm:
mov ax, 0x10
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax

mov esp, 0x9990

push ecx
push 80*25*2
call clearConsole
add esp, 4
pop ecx

push eax
push edx

push 0x1B
push hello_world
push 0
call printStr
add esp, 12

pop edx
pop eax

jmp 0x1000                  ; Jump to kernel

;void loadKernel()
loadKernel:
use16
    ; ES:BX point to input buffer. Ensure ES=0
    xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax

    ; Use valueof DL passed by bootloader for dirve number
    mov bx, 0x1000
    mov ah, 0x2
    mov al, 0x1
    mov ch, 0x0
    mov cl, 0x2
    mov dh, 0x0
    int 0x13
    ret

;void clearConsole(int value)
use32
clearConsole:
    mov ecx, 0
    loop_2:
    cmp ecx, [esp+4]
    jz exit_2
    mov al, 0
    mov ah, 0
    push ecx
    call printChar
    pop ecx
    add ecx, 2
    jmp loop_2
    exit_2:
    ret

;void printStr(byte num, char* str, byte color)
printStr:
    mov ecx, [esp+8]
loop_1:
    mov al, [ecx]
    inc ecx
    test al, al
    jz exit_1
    mov ah, [esp+12]
    push dword [esp+4]
    call printChar
    add esp, 4
    inc dword [esp+4]
    inc dword [esp+4]
    jmp loop_1
exit_1:
    ret

;void printChar(byte num, unsigned char c, byte color)
printChar:
    mov edx, 0xB8000
    add edx, [esp+4]
    mov [edx], al
    mov [edx+1], ah
    ret



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

hello_world:
db "Loading kernel...", 0

GDT:
;null
dd 0
dd 0

code:
dw 0xffff ; limit
dw 0    ; base
db 0    ; base
db 0x9a ; access rights
db 11001111b ; 4 left - flags, 4 right = limit
db 0        ; base

data:
dw 0xffff
dw 0
db 0
db 0x92
db 11001111b
db 0

gdt_desc:
dw $ - GDT -1
dd GDT

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

**loader.asm**:

```
; These symbols are defined by the linker. We use them to zero BSS section
extern __bss_start
extern __bss_sizel

use32

section .bss
align 16
stack_bottom:
resb 16384
stack_top:

section .text
extern kernel_main
global _start

_start:
    ; We need to zero out the BSS section. We'll do it a DWORD at a time
    mov edi, __bss_start        ; Start address of BSS
    mov ecx, __bss_sizel        ; Length of BSS in DWORDS
    xor eax, eax                ; Set to 0x00000000
    rep stosd                   ; Do clear using string store instruction
                                ;     Clear 4 bytes at a time

    mov esp, stack_top
    call kernel_main
    jmp $
```

**video.h**:

```
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

extern uint16_t* g_pTerminalBuffer;

#define MAX_HEIGHT  25
#define MAX_WIDTH   80

#define true 1
#define false 0

extern uint8_t g_iTerminalRow;
extern uint8_t g_iTerminalColumn;

extern void initializeTerminal();

inline uint8_t encodeColor(uint8_t foreground, uint8_t background)
{
    return foreground | background << 4;
}

inline uint16_t encodeChar(uint8_t c, uint8_t color)
{
    return (uint16_t)color << 8 | (uint16_t)c;
}
```

**video.c**:

```
#include "video.h"

uint16_t* g_pTerminalBuffer;
uint8_t g_iTerminalRow;
uint8_t g_iTerminalColumn;

void initializeTerminal()
{
    g_iTerminalRow = 0;
    g_iTerminalColumn = 0;
}
```

**kernel_main.c**:

```
#include "video.h"

extern "C" void kernel_main()
{
    g_pTerminalBuffer = (uint16_t*)0xB8000;
    g_pTerminalBuffer[2] = encodeChar('T', encodeColor(15, 0));
    while(true){}
}
```

Command to build with:

```
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
nasm -f elf32 -g -F dwarf loader.asm -o loader.o
i686-elf-c++ -O3 -g -ffreestanding -c kernel_main.c -o kernel_main.o
i686-elf-c++ -O3 -g -ffreestanding -c video.c -o video.o

ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel_main.elf loader.o video.o kernel_main.o
objcopy -O binary kernel_main.elf kernel_main.bin

dd if=/dev/zero of=image.bin bs=512 count=2880
dd if=boot.bin of=image.bin conv=notrunc
dd if=kernel_main.bin of=image.bin conv=notrunc bs=512 seek=1
```

You can run it as you were previously:

```
qemu-system-i386 -d guest_errors image.bin
```

You could run QEMU remotely using debug information with commands like these:

```
qemu-system-i386 -d guest_errors image.bin -S -s &

gdb kernel_main.elf \
        -ex 'target remote localhost:1234' \
        -ex 'break *kernel_main' \
        -ex 'layout src' \
        -ex 'layout reg' \
        -ex 'continue'
```

This sets a breakpoint on `kernel_main` symbol and uses the command line TUI interface to show the registers and source code.